# I am getting the error when i am trying to call one html page to another html page in java dynamic web application

Tags: html

Employee_Detail.css

```js
@charset "ISO-8859-1";
 *{margin:0; padding:0;}
        body{background:url(); font-family: sans-serif;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        }        
.form1{ width: 450px; background: #3e3d3d; padding: 40px 20px; box-sizing: border-box; position: fixed; left: 45%; top: 45%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);}
        h1{text-align: center; color: #fff; font-weight: normal; margin-bottom: 20px;}
 
#myHeader {
        background-color: lightblue;
        color: black;
        padding: 20px;
        text-align: center;
  } 
body {
       margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }

.topnav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
  }

.topnav a {
    float: right;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
    background-color: lightblue;
    color: black;
}

.login_form {
 transition: all 4s ease-in-out;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: oblique;
 align: center;
  }


Employee_Detail.html
```

```css
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>EmployeeDetailForm</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="form_validation.js"> </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Employee_detail.css"></link>
</head >
<body>
<h1 id="myHeader">HRMS System</h1>
<div class="topnav">
  <a href="Employee_delete.html">Delete</a>
  <a href="UserDetail.html">View</a>
  <a href='Employee_update.html'>Update</a>
  <a class="active" href="#add">Add</a>
  <a href='HomePage.xhtml'>Home</a>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>

AdminPage.html
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Employee_detail.css"></link>
</head >
<body>
<h1 id="myHeader">HRMS System</h1>
<div class="topnav">
  <a href="Employee_delete.html">Delete</a>
  <a href="UserDetail.html">View</a>
  <a href='Employee_update.html'>Update</a>  
  <a href="Employee_detail.html">Add</a>
  <a class="active" href="#Home">Home</a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**while i am clicking on Add button in AdminPage to move Employee_Detail, am getting 404 error. Morever, i am getting  below error form console like :-**

**error**
[Info]  Angular language server process ID: 4560
[Info]  Using typescript v3.8.2 from C:\Users\PAssion.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.wildwebdeveloper_0.5.5.202002262342\language-servers\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsserverlibrary.js
[Info]  Using @angular/language-service v9.0.0-rc.4 from C:\Users\PAssion.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.wildwebdeveloper_0.5.5.202002262342\language-servers\node_modules@angular\language-service\bundles\language-service.umd.js
[Info]  Log file: undefined
[Error] No config file for g:\Java Project\HRMSystem-master\WebContent\AdminPage.html
[Error] No config file for g:\Java Project\HRMSystem-master\WebContent\Employee_detail.htmlAdminPage.html